# Spin-1 representation in the Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

I am working now with spin-1 where I have instead of states $|{+1}\rangle$ and  $|{-1}\rangle$, as for in spin-1/2 case, I have  $|{+1}\rangle$,  $|0\rangle$ and  $|{-1}\rangle$. How can I check the position of my state in the Bloch sphere?

Answer (score 3):

The Bloch sphere is only useful for spin-1/2 particles, where the Hilbert space $\mathcal H\cong\mathbb C^2$ is a real manifold of dimension $4$, with one degree of freedom removed for normalization and one more removed through the irrelevant global phase, leaving you a net total of two degrees of freedom, which you then encode as the (Bloch) sphere.

For spin 1, the Hilbert space $\mathcal H\cong\mathbb C^3$ has real-manifold dimension $6$, and once you factor out normalization and global phase you're left with a state space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (the [complex projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space)), a four-dimensional real manifold that requires four real parameters in any given chart. That's not to say that this can't be done (cf. for example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4427)) but it's not something that you're going to be able to draw or even visualize as a coherent whole in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Actually, I would like to be able to see if  mathematically I could check that there is, for example, no z (|+1>) component. Can I do that by calculation expectation values or variance with the Spin matrices?